# findOneAndUpdate not returning new document in loopback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopback

I am working with loopback mongodb. Here is my query

```
const counter = await db.collection("counters").findOneAndUpdate(
  { prefix: "C" },
  { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } },
  { projection: { "sequence_value" : 1 }, returnNewDocument: true }
);
```

It returns

```
{
  lastErrorObject: { n: 1, updatedExisting: true },
  value: { _id: 'customerid', sequence_value: 590 },
  ok: 1
}
```

So I have two questions here.

1. Why it is not returning new document here? I am always getting old `sequence_value`.
2. What is `lastErrorobject` and `ok`? I only need the document object like this `{ _id: 'customerid', sequence_value: 590 }`

Answer (score 0):

```
const getCounter = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  db.collection("counters").findOneAndUpdate(
    { prefix: "C" },
    { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } },
    { projection: { "sequence_value" : 1 }, returnNewDocument: true },
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) { return reject(err); }
      resolve(result); 
    },
  );
});

const counter = await getCounter();
```

Comment: `TypeError: db.collection(...).findOneAndUpdate(...).exec is not a function` Getting error. FYI It is not mongoose. Please test it first